# How do i make a border work on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, border

I am creating a website to wish my friend on their birthday. I want it to be like a card, there is text in the center and an image of a birthday cake. i want to create a border around it to make it look like a card. i know how to change flexbox values but i really dont want to mess up. Can someone provide me the solution?

```js
var confetti = {
    maxCount: 150,      //set max confetti count
    speed: 2,           //set the particle animation speed
    frameInterval: 15,  //the confetti animation frame interval in milliseconds
    alpha: 1.0,         //the alpha opacity of the confetti (between 0 and 1, where 1 is opaque and 0 is invisible)
    gradient: false,    //whether to use gradients for the confetti particles
    start: null,        //call to start confetti animation (with optional timeout in milliseconds, and optional min and max random confetti count)
    stop: null,         //call to stop adding confetti
    toggle: null,       //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
    pause: null,        //call to freeze confetti animation
    resume: null,       //call to unfreeze confetti animation
    togglePause: null,  //call to toggle whether the confetti animation is paused
    remove: null,       //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately
    isPaused: null,     //call and returns true or false depending on whether the confetti animation is paused
    isRunning: null     //call and returns true or false depending on whether the animation is running
};

(function() {
    confetti.start = startConfetti;
    confetti.stop = stopConfetti;
    confetti.toggle = toggleConfetti;
    confetti.pause = pauseConfetti;
    confetti.resume = resumeConfetti;
    confetti.togglePause = toggleConfettiPause;
    confetti.isPaused = isConfettiPaused;
    confetti.remove = removeConfetti;
    confetti.isRunning = isConfettiRunning;
    var supportsAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    var colors = ["rgba(30,144,255,", "rgba(107,142,35,", "rgba(255,215,0,", "rgba(255,192,203,", "rgba(106,90,205,", "rgba(173,216,230,", "rgba(238,130,238,", "rgba(152,251,152,", "rgba(70,130,180,", "rgba(244,164,96,", "rgba(210,105,30,", "rgba(220,20,60,"];
    var streamingConfetti = false;
    var animationTimer = null;
    var pause = false;
    var lastFrameTime = Date.now();
    var particles = [];
    var waveAngle = 0;
    var context = null;

    function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
        particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
        particle.color2 = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
        particle.x = Math.random() * width;
        particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
        particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
        particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
        particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
        particle.tiltAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI;
        return particle;
    }

    function toggleConfettiPause() {
        if (pause)
            resumeConfetti();
        else
            pauseConfetti();
    }

    function isConfettiPaused() {
        return pause;
    }

    function pauseConfetti() {
        pause = true;
    }

    function resumeConfetti() {
        pause = false;
        runAnimation();
    }

    function runAnimation() {
        if (pause)
            return;
        else if (particles.length === 0) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            animationTimer = null;
        } else {
            var now = Date.now();
            var delta = now - lastFrameTime;
            if (!supportsAnimationFrame || delta > confetti.frameInterval) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                updateParticles();
                drawParticles(context);
                lastFrameTime = now - (delta % confetti.frameInterval);
            }
            animationTimer = requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
        }
    }

    function startConfetti(timeout, min, max) {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    return window.setTimeout(callback, confetti.frameInterval);
                };
        })();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
        if (canvas === null) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;top:0");
            document.body.prepend(canvas);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }, true);
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        } else if (context === null)
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var count = confetti.maxCount;
        if (min) {
            if (max) {
                if (min == max)
                    count = particles.length + max;
                else {
                    if (min > max) {
                        var temp = min;
                        min = max;
                        max = temp;
                    }
                    count = particles.length + ((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0);
                }
            } else
                count = particles.length + min;
        } else if (max)
            count = particles.length + max;
        while (particles.length < count)
            particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
        streamingConfetti = true;
        pause = false;
        runAnimation();
        if (timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(stopConfetti, timeout);
        }
    }

    function stopConfetti() {
        streamingConfetti = false;
    }

    function removeConfetti() {
        stop();
        pause = false;
        particles = [];
    }

    function toggleConfetti() {
        if (streamingConfetti)
            stopConfetti();
        else
            startConfetti();
    }
    
    function isConfettiRunning() {
        return streamingConfetti;
    }

    function drawParticles(context) {
        var particle;
        var x, y, x2, y2;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
            x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
            x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
            y2 = particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2;
            if (confetti.gradient) {
                var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(x, particle.y, x2, y2);
                gradient.addColorStop("0", particle.color);
                gradient.addColorStop("1.0", particle.color2);
                context.strokeStyle = gradient;
            } else
                context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
            context.moveTo(x, particle.y);
            context.lineTo(x2, y2);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function updateParticles() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var particle;
        waveAngle += 0.01;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
                particle.y = height + 100;
            else {
                particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
                particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle) - 0.5;
                particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + confetti.speed) * 0.5;
                particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
            }
            if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
                if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= confetti.maxCount)
                    resetParticle(particle, width, height);
                else {
                    particles.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--emoji-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <!--title-->
    <title>&#127881;Happy Birthday&#127881;</title>
    <!--animation-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <!--favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!--CSS-->
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body style="background-color:hsl(0, 0%, 0%); width: 100%; height: 100%;">
     <div class="animated pulse infinite" style="font-size: 90px; color:#06589c ; text-shadow: 0 0 2rem #06589c; font-family:'Raleway'; text-align: center; margin-top: 55px; font-weight: bold;">Happy Birthday Eshal!</div>
     <div class="Birthday Cake" style="text-align: center;">
     <img src="images/favicon.png" width="346.4px" height="310.8px" alt="Birthday Cake" style="text-shadow: 0 0 2rem white;">
     </div> 

     <script src="confetti.js"></script>
     <!-- Confetti  JS-->
     <script>

         // start

         const start = () => {
             setTimeout(function() {
                 confetti.start()
             }, 1000); // 1000 is time that after 1 second start the confetti ( 1000 = 1 sec)
         };

         //  Stop

         const stop = () => {
             setTimeout(function() {
                 confetti.stop()
             }, 5000); // 5000 is time that after 5 second stop the confetti ( 5000 = 5 sec)
         };

         start();
         stop();
     </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp

Comment: @JoséLourenço no not a card like that. i meant like a birthday card. i just want a border around the content of the page thats it. but i just cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do.
Here is one way to do by adding it on html directly, but I don't know what border type you are trying to set.

```css
html{
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

### DEMO

```js
var confetti = {
    maxCount: 150,      //set max confetti count
    speed: 2,           //set the particle animation speed
    frameInterval: 15,  //the confetti animation frame interval in milliseconds
    alpha: 1.0,         //the alpha opacity of the confetti (between 0 and 1, where 1 is opaque and 0 is invisible)
    gradient: false,    //whether to use gradients for the confetti particles
    start: null,        //call to start confetti animation (with optional timeout in milliseconds, and optional min and max random confetti count)
    stop: null,         //call to stop adding confetti
    toggle: null,       //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
    pause: null,        //call to freeze confetti animation
    resume: null,       //call to unfreeze confetti animation
    togglePause: null,  //call to toggle whether the confetti animation is paused
    remove: null,       //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately
    isPaused: null,     //call and returns true or false depending on whether the confetti animation is paused
    isRunning: null     //call and returns true or false depending on whether the animation is running
};

(function() {
    confetti.start = startConfetti;
    confetti.stop = stopConfetti;
    confetti.toggle = toggleConfetti;
    confetti.pause = pauseConfetti;
    confetti.resume = resumeConfetti;
    confetti.togglePause = toggleConfettiPause;
    confetti.isPaused = isConfettiPaused;
    confetti.remove = removeConfetti;
    confetti.isRunning = isConfettiRunning;
    var supportsAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    var colors = ["rgba(30,144,255,", "rgba(107,142,35,", "rgba(255,215,0,", "rgba(255,192,203,", "rgba(106,90,205,", "rgba(173,216,230,", "rgba(238,130,238,", "rgba(152,251,152,", "rgba(70,130,180,", "rgba(244,164,96,", "rgba(210,105,30,", "rgba(220,20,60,"];
    var streamingConfetti = false;
    var animationTimer = null;
    var pause = false;
    var lastFrameTime = Date.now();
    var particles = [];
    var waveAngle = 0;
    var context = null;

    function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
        particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
        particle.color2 = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
        particle.x = Math.random() * width;
        particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
        particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
        particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
        particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
        particle.tiltAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI;
        return particle;
    }

    function toggleConfettiPause() {
        if (pause)
            resumeConfetti();
        else
            pauseConfetti();
    }

    function isConfettiPaused() {
        return pause;
    }

    function pauseConfetti() {
        pause = true;
    }

    function resumeConfetti() {
        pause = false;
        runAnimation();
    }

    function runAnimation() {
        if (pause)
            return;
        else if (particles.length === 0) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            animationTimer = null;
        } else {
            var now = Date.now();
            var delta = now - lastFrameTime;
            if (!supportsAnimationFrame || delta > confetti.frameInterval) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                updateParticles();
                drawParticles(context);
                lastFrameTime = now - (delta % confetti.frameInterval);
            }
            animationTimer = requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
        }
    }

    function startConfetti(timeout, min, max) {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    return window.setTimeout(callback, confetti.frameInterval);
                };
        })();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
        if (canvas === null) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;top:0");
            document.body.prepend(canvas);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }, true);
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        } else if (context === null)
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var count = confetti.maxCount;
        if (min) {
            if (max) {
                if (min == max)
                    count = particles.length + max;
                else {
                    if (min > max) {
                        var temp = min;
                        min = max;
                        max = temp;
                    }
                    count = particles.length + ((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0);
                }
            } else
                count = particles.length + min;
        } else if (max)
            count = particles.length + max;
        while (particles.length < count)
            particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
        streamingConfetti = true;
        pause = false;
        runAnimation();
        if (timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(stopConfetti, timeout);
        }
    }

    function stopConfetti() {
        streamingConfetti = false;
    }

    function removeConfetti() {
        stop();
        pause = false;
        particles = [];
    }

    function toggleConfetti() {
        if (streamingConfetti)
            stopConfetti();
        else
            startConfetti();
    }
    
    function isConfettiRunning() {
        return streamingConfetti;
    }

    function drawParticles(context) {
        var particle;
        var x, y, x2, y2;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
            x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
            x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
            y2 = particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2;
            if (confetti.gradient) {
                var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(x, particle.y, x2, y2);
                gradient.addColorStop("0", particle.color);
                gradient.addColorStop("1.0", particle.color2);
                context.strokeStyle = gradient;
            } else
                context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
            context.moveTo(x, particle.y);
            context.lineTo(x2, y2);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function updateParticles() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var particle;
        waveAngle += 0.01;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
                particle.y = height + 100;
            else {
                particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
                particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle) - 0.5;
                particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + confetti.speed) * 0.5;
                particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
            }
            if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
                if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= confetti.maxCount)
                    resetParticle(particle, width, height);
                else {
                    particles.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
html{
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--emoji-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <!--title-->
    <title>&#127881;Happy Birthday&#127881;</title>
    <!--animation-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <!--favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!--CSS-->
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body style="background-color:hsl(0, 0%, 0%); width: 100%; height: 100%;">
     <div class="animated pulse infinite" style="font-size: 90px; color:#06589c ; text-shadow: 0 0 2rem #06589c; font-family:'Raleway'; text-align: center; margin-top: 55px; font-weight: bold;">Happy Birthday Eshal!</div>
     <div class="Birthday Cake" style="text-align: center;">
     <img src="images/favicon.png" width="346.4px" height="310.8px" alt="Birthday Cake" style="text-shadow: 0 0 2rem white;">
     </div> 

     <script src="confetti.js"></script>
     <!-- Confetti  JS-->
     <script>

         // start

         const start = () => {
             setTimeout(function() {
                 confetti.start()
             }, 1000); // 1000 is time that after 1 second start the confetti ( 1000 = 1 sec)
         };

         //  Stop

         const stop = () => {
             setTimeout(function() {
                 confetti.stop()
             }, 5000); // 5000 is time that after 5 second stop the confetti ( 5000 = 5 sec)
         };

         start();
         stop();
     </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```